# I need to change the style and control use of the asp:Login control button

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, asp.net-membership

Is it possible to get the source and code behind of the control so I can manipulate it myself?

That way I can keep using the Membership and have the ease of functionality, but can use my own controls.

I'm sure there is an easy solution to this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use templates as per below for the Login control. Note that you'll need to provide your own validators etc if you do this, but you're allowed much more freedom :)

If you place a login control in VS, then open up the context box for it, and click 'Convert to Template', you can see what the standard implementation is like.

```
<asp:Login ... >
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" ... /> ...
        <asp:TextBox ID="Password" ... /> ...
        <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" ... />
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:Login>
```